# In Laravel how to json response show in ajax?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

Kindly check json response from one to many relation. I want to show this response in ajax. But i don't know how to show in ajax. how to show in success response.

```
{
   "extra":{
      "values":[
         [
            {
               "id":9,
               "extra_name":"Ihr Dip:",
               "status":"open",
               "created_at":"2022-04-19T16:47:35.000000Z",
               "updated_at":"2022-04-19T16:47:35.000000Z",
               "created_by":"1",
               "updated_by":null,
               "extra":[
                  {
                     "id":17,
                     "description":"mit Kr\u00e4uter-Remoulade",
                     "status":"open",
                     "main_extra_id":"9",
                     "price":"1,00",
                     "created_at":"2022-04-19T16:47:55.000000Z",
                     "updated_at":"2022-04-19T16:47:55.000000Z",
                     "created_by":"1",
                     "updated_by":null
                  },
                  {
                     "id":18,
                     "description":"mit Pizza Max Ketchup 40ml",
                     "status":"open",
                     "main_extra_id":"9",
                     "price":"10,70",
                     "created_at":"2022-04-19T16:48:14.000000Z",
                     "updated_at":"2022-04-19T16:48:14.000000Z",
                     "created_by":"1",
                     "updated_by":null
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will automatically serialize your Eloquent models and collections to JSON when they are returned from routes or controllers:

```
Route::get('users', function () {
    return User::all();
});
```

See below link:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#relationships

Another example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return Post::latest()
                ->with('category', 'author')->get();
    }
}
```